# TypeError: 'TextClause' object is not iterable

Tags: python, mysql, flask

PythonのフレームワークであるFlaskで、データベース内を検索しようとすると、TypeError: 'TextClause' object is not iterableというエラーが発生します。sqlchemyでコードを実装すると上手くいくのですが、Mysqlだとどうしても上手くいきません。

実際のコードは、こちらです。

Mysql版

```
@app.route("/search",methods=["POST"])
def search():
    req = request.form["input"]
    searches = text(""" SELECT * FROM store WHERE title LIKE '%s%' """)
    return render_template("search/search.html",searches=searches)
```

sqlchemyだと上手くいきます。

```
@app.route("/cast")
def cast():
    casts = Cast.query.all()
    return render_template("cast.html",casts=casts,title=Cast.title,content=Cast.content)

    #searches = db.session.query(Store).\
                                                     filter(or_(\
                                                     Store.title.like("%" + req + "%"),\
                                                     Store.content.like("%" + req + "%"),\
                                                     Store.Region.like("%" + req + "%"),\
                                                     )).all()
```

```html
{% extends "base.html"%}
{% block content %}

{% for search in searches %}
<div class="card" style="margin-top:60px;">
    <h2>{{ search.title }}</h2>
    <p>{{ search.content }}</p>
    <p>{{ search.Region}}</p>
</div>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

誰か分かる人は、何が原因なのかを教えていただけると幸いです。

Comment: `text()`は自作関数でしょうか？それならばその部分のソースも無いと答えが得られないのでは？[Using Flask on Python 3 with MySQL](https://sweetcode.io/flask-python-3-mysql/)

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。text()は、公式ドキュメントによるとsqlchemyでmysqlのコマンドがかける物です。

Comment: これら [Flask – SQLAlchemy](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/flask/flask_sqlalchemy.htm), [Python sqlalchemy.text() Examples](https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/51676/sqlalchemy.text) を見ると、`text()`と`render_template()`の間に、`xxxx.execute()`等で`query`を行う処理が必要では？

Comment: 'TextClause' object is not iterable　のとおり、searches　か何かがiterableでないということかな？と思います。リストとか文字列みたいな感じではなく、想像されているのと違って、複数に分けさせてくれないものという感じでしょうか？